# NextJS performing full reload when saving module.css files imported by components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Whenever I save a file located at app/components/<Component>/<component>.module.css, which is imported by app/components/<Component>/<Component>.js, NextJS performs a full reload. This doesn't happen if a .module.css file is imported by a page, such as app/page.js (styles from page.module.css). This also doesn't happen if I import a normal .css file in to a component; only when a .module.css file is imported to a component.

Even placing both the component and the <component>.module.css file at the root of the /app directory (exactly the same as the page.js and page.module.css files) doesn't fix this.

It seems no matter where the component and its style file are located, this continues to happen. I am using the App Router for the first time, but could not find any information which would suggest that module.css files can't be used for components.